# I need to implement SEARCH BY YEAR and SEARCH WITH DATE PICKER

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search, datepicker

I have an invoice application with multiple search functionality (searching invoices by type, status and customer id). I need to implement search only by year, and additional search by datepicker (for two separate views). Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(InvoiceViewModel invoiceViewModel)
    {
        LoadStatus();
        LoadInvoiceType();

        invoiceViewModel.CustomerModelList = customerRepository.All();
        invoiceViewModel.InvoiceList = invoiceRepository.All()
            .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceViewModel.InvoiceCode),x=> x.InvoiceCode == invoiceViewModel.InvoiceCode)
            .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceViewModel.Type), x => x.Type == invoiceViewModel.Type)
            .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceViewModel.Status), x => x.Status == invoiceViewModel.Status)
             .WhereIf(invoiceViewModel.CustomerId.HasValue, x => x.CustomerId == invoiceViewModel.CustomerId.Value)
             .Include(x => x.CustomerModel).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

        invoiceViewModel.count = invoiceViewModel.InvoiceList.Count();
        return View("Index",invoiceViewModel);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<script>    
$(function () {
    $(".mydatepicker").datepicker();

    $(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
    });
});    
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Invoice", FormMethod.Get))
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "InvoiceCode", @placeholder = "Invoice code" } })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.CustomerModelList, "Id", "Name"), "select Customer", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "CustomerId" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, ViewData["invoicetype"] as List<SelectListItem>, "select type", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Type" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, ViewData["country"] as List<SelectListItem>, "select status", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Status" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFrom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control mydatepicker", @id = "DateFrom", @placeholder = "Date From" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control mydatepicker", @placeholder = "Due Date", @id = "DueDate" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="submit" style="width: 100%" id="btnSubmit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="submit" style="width: 100%" id="btnSubmit" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary" />  
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Year` property to the `InvoiceViewModel` class and make your `DateFrom` and `DateTo` nullable by adding `?` to the property type

```
public int? Year { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
```

Add list of valid years to the `ViewData`

```
ViewData["years"] = new List<SelectListItem> { /* add display and value here */ };
```

Add `DropDownList` to view

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, ViewData["country"] as List<SelectListItem>, "select year", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Year" })
</div>
```

Add releated code to you controller

```
public ActionResult Search(InvoiceViewModel invoiceViewModel)
{
    LoadStatus();
    LoadInvoiceType();

    invoiceViewModel.CustomerModelList = customerRepository.All();
    invoiceViewModel.InvoiceList = invoiceRepository.All()
        .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceViewModel.InvoiceCode),x=> x.InvoiceCode == invoiceViewModel.InvoiceCode)
        .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceViewModel.Type), x => x.Type == invoiceViewModel.Type)
        .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceViewModel.Status), x => x.Status == invoiceViewModel.Status)
        // search the year of the needed date
        .WhereIf(invoiceViewModel.Year.HasValue, x => x.[date].Year == invoiceViewModel.Year)
        // search the needed date range
        .WhereIf(invoiceViewModel.DateFrom.HasValue, x => x.[date] >= invoiceViewModel.DateFrom)
        .WhereIf(invoiceViewModel.DateTo.HasValue, x => x.[date] <= invoiceViewModel.DateTo)

        .WhereIf(invoiceViewModel.CustomerId.HasValue, x => x.CustomerId == invoiceViewModel.CustomerId.Value)
        .Include(x => x.CustomerModel).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

    invoiceViewModel.count = invoiceViewModel.InvoiceList.Count();
    return View("Index",invoiceViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, everything else worked, except I do not understand where should I add the ViewData (in model, controller) and how to display the values?

Comment: ViewData is set in the controller, and I'm not sure what values you want to display ?

Comment: Values - I meant the year range. Sorry for the poorly formed question.

Comment: Same way you used the `DropDownListFor` in the view for `invoicetype`

Comment: If you mean getting the data itself you can either start from a known date in database or just put it manually in the list

Comment: it works, thank you! But when I search by year, the button shows me the results in different view (Invoices) not in InvoicesByYear. How do I fix that?

this is my button

<input type="submit" style="width: 100%" id="btnSubmit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" 
                         onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SearchByYear")'">

Comment: I think this might help you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managing-multiple-submit-buttons-on-single-view-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped!